# Is my 13" rMBP capable of running a 4k monitor at 2560x1440 scaled resolution?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, resolution

I have a late 2013 13" rMBP and a 4k monitor (3840x2160) that's running at 60Hz over mini display port. Right now it uses a scaled 1920x1080 resolution so everything is displayed at 2x HDPI (retina mode), which seems to be default.

Everything is a bit big for my liking, however, and on the flip side 3840x2160 is far too small, so I was hoping to go for around 2560x1440 for a happy medium.

As System Preferences seemingly doesn't permit this, I downloaded SwitchResX, created a custom resolution ("scaled" mode and 2560x1440 resolution) and selected "save", rebooted, but it still won't show up in System Preferences.

What am I doing wrong? Is my computer not capable of displaying that resolution (I realize it has to scale it up to 5120x2880 first)?

Comment: Did you figure out how to let it work at 2560x1440? I looked so long for a good WQHD monitor for my rMBP, but I think it is better and easier to just get a 4K monitor.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how you managed to run it at 60Hz? Everything I found said this was not possible. And did you manage to run it at 2560x1440 now? How does it look?

Comment: For anyone interested, 52Hz seems to be possible: https://kandrejevs.com/blog/read/50/More-than-30Hz-on-Your-133-Macbook-Pro-and-4K-monitor

Answer (score -1):

Option-clicking the scaled button in System Prefs will bring up many more options.

Comment: None of which are HDPI like I'm asking.